# No debug.print output when changing value in a dependent cell [VBA]

Tags: excel, vba

To start off, my original problem is that I am trying to crate a forecast output from some data that I have filtered out of a range using two conditions.

My first problem is that I cannot figure out how to create a "dataset" that can be put into the Forecast function as known_y's and known_x's.

When using debug.print to check the output to see if I get the right output of which I could maybe put into arrays, I get the output:

```
    14/12/2022 
     16.1919058436079 
    25/10/2023 
     17.4970515732711 
    30/06/2025 
     23.651141167206
```

if I change this value, which I have in the cell N10, I don't get an output at all, even though the value I change to is for sure in the original range. thoughts anyone?

my code so far:

```
Sub companyforecast()

Dim i As Integer, dates As Variant, assetswaps As Variant, arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant


Worksheets("Spain").Select

ActiveSheet.Calculate

With ActiveSheet
    totalbonds = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row - 10
    For i = 1 To totalbonds
        If .Cells(10 + i, 4).Value = .Range("N10").Value And .Cells(10 + i, 6).Value < .Cells(8, 16) Then
        Debug.Print .Cells(10 + i, 6).Value
        Debug.Print .Cells(10 + i, 10).Value


               
        End If
    Next i
    'ActiveSheet.Cells(22, 16).Value = ActiveSheet.WorksheetFunction.Forecast(Cells(8, 16), dates, assetswaps).Value

End With
'Debug.Print dates
'Debug.Print assetswaps
End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like `If .Cells(10 + i, 4).Value = .Range("N10").Value And .Cells(10 + i, 6).Value < .Cells(8, 16) Then` evaluates to `False` then.

Comment: Hello, the second section after AND is checking if a date in the range is before a date in a specific cell (8,16), and that is indeed true. This puzzles me even further

Comment: Maybe put `Debug.Print .Cells(10 + i, 4).Value = .Range("N10").Value And .Cells(10 + i, 6).Value < .Cells(8, 16)` before the `If` to see what it actually evaluates to.

Comment: I tested to remove the statement after AND and I got a result, then I tried to only include the second statement. Doing this resulted in printing only 3 values, where the 4th date would have been higher than the one in cells(8,16). however, further down the column there are dates that should be included which are not. All dates are European, I double checked

Comment: I don't have your workbook in hand... but the *only* reason that you don't get any output is that the condition evaluates to `False`.

Comment: Solved first part, I was required to "text to column" the remaining dates in the column.

Comment: Step through the code and see if it passes over the `if` statement